# Can std::atomic be safely used with OpenMP

Tags: c++, c++11, openmp, atomic, stdatomic

I'm currently trying to learn ow to use OpenMP and I have a question.
Is it safe to do something like that :

```
  std::atomic<double> result;
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(...)
  {
  result+= //some stuff;
  }
```

Or shall I use :

```
  double result;
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(...)
  {
    double tmp=0;
    //some stuff;
    #pragma omp atomic
    result+=tmp;
  }
```

Thanks !

Edit : I know the most simple way to handle that is using an array, but Im asking because I'm curious

Comment: `std::atomic` is a facility provided by the C++11 standard's multithreading framework. If you use `std::atomic` in combination with external libraries like OpenMP, which provide their own implementations of such features, you will likely run into problems.

Comment: Actually, the atomic library is specified in a different chapter in the standard than the thread library. Also, I haven't found any remark in the atomic chapter saying that this library is only intended for use with std::thread.

Comment: i agree with @gTcV - atomic types operate with c++ memory model, not threading implementation. For example,this would make use of smart pointers inside omp sections cause race condition for reference counter

Comment: GCC used to generate an error for the case where you want to use C11 or C++11 atomics inside OpenMP parallel regions. If OpenMP atomics don't introduce any additional complexity than using C++11's, I would stick with the former, since you will only depend on OpenMP standard (you could use compilers without C++11 support).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mixing C++11 atomics and OpenMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41309299/mixing-c11-atomics-and-openmp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Officially, no. In practice, probably.

Page Section 1.7 page 32 of the [OpenMP 5.0 Specification](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5.0.pdf#page=52) says:

> While future versions of the OpenMP specification are expected to address the following features, currently their use may result in unspecified behavior.
>
> - Concurrency
> - Additions to the standard library
> - C++11 Library

However, depending on the implementation of the OpenMP runtime you use, it *might* be alright. In fact, the LLVM OpenMP runtime even uses [`std::atomic`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/openmp/blob/3eae253b1ac2da31d8928950dcb50956b64e81d1/runtime/src/kmp_lock.cpp#L14) to implement some of the OpenMP specification.

The safest option though is to stick with using only what OpenMP provides. Anything you can do using `std::atomic` you should also be able to achieve using only OpenMP.

Comment: This has been fixed in OpenMP 5.1: https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-1.pdf

Comment: "Anything you can do using std::atomic you should also be able to achieve using only OpenMP." Can you elaborate more on that?  
std::atomic is used for lock free programming, like for example updating a shared counter without using mutex and critical sections. How can openMP do that?

Comment: https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu95.html

Answer (score -2):

Since atomics slow down parallel execution and don't scale well, better do

```
pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:result)
for(...)
{
  double tmp=0;
  //some stuff;
  result+=tmp;
}
```