# Avoiding race condition in OpenMP?

Tags: openmp, shared-memory, race-condition, critical-section

I was reading about OpenMP and shared memory programming and fell over this pseudo code that has an integer x and two threads

```
thread 1
x++;

thread 2
x--;
```

This will lead to a race condition, but can be avoided. I want to avoid it using OpenMP, how should it be done?

This is how I think it will be avoided:

```
int x;
#pragma omp parallel shared(X) num_threads(2)

int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
if(tid == 1)
    x++;
else
    x--;
```

I know that by eliminating the race condition will lead to correct execution but also poor performance, but I don't know why?

Comment: The code you show has *exactly* the problem you describe; it doesn't avoid it at all.  It's not a problem if `x` is declared as a suitable `std::atomic` integer, but since you haven't shown us what type it is, we can only gues...

Comment: @TobySpeight: I have shown that x is an integer. Furthermore, that's the snippet that were in my reading material.

Comment: @TobySpeight wrong - *The thread number is an integer between 0 and one less than the value returned by omp_get_num_threads, inclusive.*

Comment: The question makes no sense to me. Either your reading material is really bad, or you need to revisit the basics.

Comment: @TobySpeight: so the solution is to change `if(tid == 1)` to `if(tid == 0)`

Comment: @Zulan: I got the pseudo code from my reading material

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If more than one thread is modifying `x`, the code is at risk from a race condition.  Taking a simplified version of your example

```c++
int main()
{
    int x = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel sections
    {
        #pragma omp section {
            ++x;
        }
        #pragma omp section {
            --x;
        }
    }

    return x;
}
```

The two threads modifying `x` may be interleaved with each other, meaning that the result will not necessarily be zero.

One way to protect the modifications is to wrap the read-modify-write code in a `critical` region.

Another, that suitable for the simple operations here, is to mark the `++` and `--` lines with `#pragma omp atomic` - that will use platform-native atomic instructions where they exist, which is lightweight compared to a critical region.

Another approach that *usually* works (but isn't strictly guaranteed by OpenMP) is to change the type used for `x` to a standard atomic type.  Simply changing it from `int` to `std::atomic<int>` gives you indivisible `++` and `--` operators which you can use here.

Comment: The question omits the idiomatic solution: `#pragma omp atomic`. [Using `std::atomic` with OpenMP is not explicitly specified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41316118/620382).