# OpenMP and shared_ptr

Tags: multithreading, c++11, openmp

Is it safe to use a `shared_ptr` inside an OpenMP parallel block in any way? A `shared_ptr` maintains atomicity of reference count through the use of an atomic and in general it is my understanding that we should not be mixing C++11 multi-threading mechanisms with OpenMP. So by definition it seems to me that accessing a shared_ptr anywhere inside an `pragma omp` block (even for simple const read operations) could cause problems. Or this is not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is quite correct. First, take a look at this question about [OpenMP and `std::atomic`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41309299/mixing-c11-atomics-and-openmp). Note that, `std::shared_ptr` isn't *necessarily* implemented using atomics. Also this applies to the shared control block, which is modified with during copy operations. There are a couple of cases:

- Calling `get` / `operator->` / `operator*` with one `shared_ptr` per thread that points to the same object. Only performing read-only operations on the target object. This is as safe as it gets given the specification-gap between C++11 and OpenMP. No control-block operations are performed. I would argue that this is not different from using a raw pointer.
- Calling `get` / `operator->` / `operator*` on one shared `shared_ptr` from multiple threads. This is still similarly safe.
- Copying / deleting thread-local `shared_ptr`s that points to different objects across multiple threads. This should still be as safe as it gets as there is no shared date.
- Copying / deleting thread-local `shared_ptr`s that point to the same object from multiple threads. Now we know this involves shared control date, but it is safe according to the C++ standard. The argument for `std::atomic` / OpenMP applies. It is practically safe but not very well defined.
- Modifying (`reset`) a thread-shared `shared_ptr` across mutiple threads. This is unsafe. `atomic<shared_ptr>` can be used here, but then the same argument applies.

I would make one more distinction. If you consider using `std::atomic` with OpenMP there is the alternative of using the OpenMP-idiomatic `pragma omp atomic` - there is no OpenMP equivalent to `shared_ptr`. So short of implementing your own `shared_ptr` on top of `omp atomic` you don't really have a choice.